# Issue when clicking on the table of contents of some sections

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

The table of contents of my document indicates the right page of each section but when I click in the first four appendices I do not get into the correct page.

It only happens with 4 sections (A.1,A.2,A.3 and A.4) of the Appendix chapter. The code defining the Appendix chapter is the following:

```
   \titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-19pt}{0pt}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\clearpage
 \section{Assessment of water resources in endorheic basins}
  %\input{Appendixx/AppendixTable1}
  \clearpage
   \section{RS applications for the assessment of water resources in endorheic basins}
  %\input{Appendixx/AppendixTable3}
  \clearpage
 \section{Placement of ROIs within the DP system}
  %\input{Appendixx/Appendix A}
    \clearpage
 \section{Water mask extracted from the MNDWI}
  %\input{Appendixx/Appendix B}
    \clearpage
 \section{Estimated precipitation (CHIRPS) versus reference precipitation (rain-gauge)}
  %\input{Appendixx/Appendix C}
    \clearpage
 \section{Temporal evolution of annual precipitation of rain-gauge (black line) and CHIRPS (blue line)}
  %\input{Appendixx/Appendix D}
  \clearpage
```

Inputs (Appendix A, B, C and D) are figures which have exactly the same code in the .txt file:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]%{figures/prueba_biasStaations.jpg}
\label{fig:biasStaations}
\end{figure}
```

The only difference between appendices is the **.jpg** file. However, only Appendix A.5 (Appendix C) and A.6 (Appendix D) are correctly linked with their page.

This is the main.txt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}% breks long URL.
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%%% Bibliography%%%%%
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
    backend=bibtex,
    sortcites=ynt,
uniquename=init,
natbib=true,
    maxbibnames=15,
    maxcitenames=2,
    dashed=false] {biblatex}

%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%\input{thesis.preamble}


\begin{document}

\title{\LARGE {\bf Mapping historical hydrological changes in the Lake Poopó catchment, Bolivia, with remote sensing}
 \vspace*{6mm}
}

\author{Juan Torres-Batlló}
\submitdate{June 2020}

\normallinespacing

\body
%\input{background/Chapter 2}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

%\printbibliography
   
%\input{Appendices2}

\end{document}
```

The first 4 appendices [A.1 (Table1),A.2 (Table2), A.3 (A) and A.4 (B) are not well referenced]. The 2 last appendices [A.5(D) and A.6 (C)] are well referenced and when I click on them in the TOC the hyperlink brings me to the correct page. However, with the 2 first appendices when I click on them in the TOC the link does not bring me to the correct page.

[image]

Is there any issue with the code?

Comment: I bet you get warnings in the logs about duplicate destinations.

Comment: I cannot find the duplicate destination issue in the logs. However, when I only use the Appendix as an input without including \input{Introduction}, \input{Chapter 2}, etc. the Taable of Contents refer to the right page when clicking in all the Appendices. If I include my \input{Introduction} or any other \input .txt, then some of the Appendices do not refer me to the right page.

Comment: well then you will have to make a proper, complete example that can be used for tests. Snippets with local \input files and graphics are useless.

Comment: I just edited the principal question. Thanks

Comment: You still have lots of local files. Remove them and replace them by simple text. If the bibliography is not relevant for your problem, remove it from the example.  Remove the \include in the preamble (and in your real document replace it with \input, \include should not be used there).

Comment: All the local files have been replace it by simple text by adding % at the beginning of the line. I also replaced the \include by \input in the preamble. Thanks.

Comment: Hm. I suspect you removed too much now. Does your example still demonstate the problem?

Comment: I just figured it out. I had a local file defining the appendix section. I just removed it and now the link from TOC brings me to the right page in all the appendices. Thanks